# iframe html code is showing as plain text in tabl

Tags: html, iframe

[image: iframe not showing]

There are many question like this in stackoverflow but without answer that is why I am asking this question . This is showing only text not html iframe inside table td

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head></head> <body>  <iframe width="1280" height="609" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VOoGQIBj9_Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>  </body> </html>
```

my code - this is working fine in w3schools but not here

Comment: Can you share your code? Maybe you are actually including the code within `<iframe>` tags. The source of the iframe should be in a separate html file and then associated with the iframe using the `src` attribute..

Comment: Perhaps you used some unusual html tag in your code. Could you please share your code for me to see?

Comment: I have edited the post please refresh and see the code

Comment: What might be happening is that the HTML values you're submitting in the Link field are being sanitised with [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or similar. The results of this will cause the code you've entered to be output as `&lt;iframe ...` instead of `<iframe ...` which is why the content is being shown as plain text, rather than HTML tags. The CMS you're using would be doing this for security reasons, so you'd need to dig into the documentation for the CMS you're using, or contact the developers to see if it supports raw HTML another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. Try only adding code withing iframe tag instead of whole HTML code.

```html
 <iframe width="1280" height="609" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VOoGQIBj9_Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: @rahul Have you only tried the url `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/VOoGQIBj9_Y` ?

Comment: This code works fine on my side. just strange.